# SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException after upgrading to Android 6 (Marshmallow)

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-6.0-marshmallow, activeandroid

I have an application in the PlayStore, and some users reported that it no longer worked after they updated their phones to android 6. The stack trace associated to the reports is the following

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application ar.com.package.android.MyApp: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4731)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1415)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:207)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:191)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:806)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:791)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:694)
at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:571)
at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:269)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:223)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
at com.activeandroid.Cache.openDatabase(Cache.java:106)
at com.activeandroid.Cache.initialize(Cache.java:75)
at com.activeandroid.ActiveAndroid.initialize(ActiveAndroid.java:44)
at com.activeandroid.ActiveAndroid.initialize(ActiveAndroid.java:34)
at com.activeandroid.ActiveAndroid.initialize(ActiveAndroid.java:30)
at com.activeandroid.app.Application.onCreate(Application.java:25)
at ar.com.package.android.MyApp.onCreate(MyApp.java:33)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1036)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4728)
```

Obviously the problem is related to ActiveAndroid (which I use in this app) not being able to open the database, but I wasn't able to reproduce the error as the conditions for it are very specific (Installing the app in a lolipop phone > updating the phone to marshmallow). A clean install on marshmallow works perfectly.
My first tought was the new permissions system in marshmallow, but as far as I tested I didn't find any problem with that. Just in case, here is the list of permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

If anyone has an idea of what could the problem be, that would help me a lot.